# How to set proxy Internet Connections and change immediately?

Tags: c++, c, windows, proxy

i want to set proxy. currently code. it set the proxy with registry but it will take effect not immediately. it need restart.  how make a effect immediately. or theres some api or ways to accomplish this?

```
    #include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    HKEY hKey;
    RegCreateKeyExW(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings", 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_WRITE, NULL, &hKey, NULL);
    DWORD value = 0;
    RegSetValueExW(hKey, L"ProxyEnable", 0, REG_DWORD, (const BYTE*)&value, sizeof(value));
    RegCloseKey(hKey);
    SendNotifyMessageW(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you programming in C or C++?  C++ can model GUI widgets through inheritance.  The C language doesn't have classes or inheritance.  The C++ language as `std::string`, C only has character arrays.  Please update your tags accordingly.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews the problem is not the language. its a ways. c/c++ can work together. so i think its still related.

Comment: That's NOT how to configure proxy settings in Windows. You need to call `InternetSetOptionA` with `INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION` and `INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY_SETTINGS_CHANGED` to notify of proxy settings changes.